# d3.js - Plotting points on zoomable, clickable map

Tags: csv, plot, maps, d3.js

I am trying to adapt the map found at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340 and plot some points on it.  I have the data I am trying to use (latitudes and longitudes) in a csv file called data.csv, which is formatted like this:

```
lon_0,lat_0,lon_1,lat_1
-122.1430195,37.4418834,-122.415278,37.778643
-122.1430195,37.4418834,-122.40815,37.785034
-122.4194155,37.7749295,-122.4330827,37.7851673
-122.4194155,37.7749295,-122.4330827,37.7851673
-118.4911912,34.0194543,-118.3672828,33.9164666
-121.8374777,39.7284944,-121.8498415,39.7241178
-115.172816,36.114646,-115.078011,36.1586877
```

The modification to the code I made is contained in the following snippet

```
d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {
  d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
   dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["lat_0"], +d["lon_0"] ]; });
   console.log(data)
   states.selectAll("circle")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([d["lon_0"], d["lat_0"] ])[0];
               })
     .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([d["lon_0"],d["lat_0"] ])[1];
               })
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red");

});

  states.selectAll("path")
      .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", click);


});
```

The map renders fine, but the plots are not shown.  Any idea what could be wrong here?  I've tried a bunch of different things, I'm not sure if it is a matter of the states map covering the points, or if something is wrong with the projection...

Comment: Did you see [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)? It uses a slightly different approach but explains all the steps.

Comment: I saw this tutorial, but assumed that the way that the cities are plotted was not incredibly relevant, since they are being loaded directly from a topoJSON object.  It wasn't clear to me that the content there could be applied to loading from a csv, etc.

Comment: You could combine the two data sets which would make them easier to plot. Anyway, it looks to me like you're passing the string values of the coordinates to the projection instead of the numbers that you're creating in `dataset`. Am I missing something or is this the problem?

Comment: That problem would be solved by using `+d["lon_0"]`, right?  I have tried switching between these two in de-bugging, but it has no effect.  The red circle elements exist if I look at the elements generated (e.g., `<circle cx="-807.6795270197106" cy="1788.5726972077325" r="5" style="fill: #ff0000;"></circle>`), they're just not visible.

Comment: Are you filling the paths generated later by any chance? If so, they would obscure the points. Try moving the code that generates the paths before the code that does the points.

Comment: Success -- thanks!  I could have sworn I tried this earlier, but guess I was doing something wrong...

Comment: Cool. I'll add this as an answer for future reference.

Comment: Did you get it working so your circles move when you click and zoom? To get it working, I've had to rename your "states" variable to the "g" variable in the current mbostock link. But when I click and zoom, my map moves but not my circles. Thanks! BH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paths drawn in the example are filled, i.e. anything behind them will be obscured. SVG elements are drawn in the order they are specified. In your case, the circles are drawn first and then the paths for the states, thereby obscuring the circles.

It works when you draw the state paths before drawing the circles.