# Add a circle to a d3.js map

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have generated a map of Phoenix from this [GeoJson](https://github.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/blob/master/public/data/phoenix.geojson) and made it show as I would like it to.

Now I would like to add circles to the map to represent something of interest, but the circles never show up. Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var h = 1280;
    var w = 1280;

    var projection = d3.geo.albers().scale(80000).center([0, 33.44]).rotate([112.07, 0]).translate([920, 850]);
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

    d3.json("data/phoenix.json", function(json) {
        svg.selectAll("path").data(json.features).enter().append("path")
               .attr("d", path).style("fill", "grey");

        var coordinates = projection([33.46764,112.0785]);
        svg.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", coordinates[0])
                .attr("cy", coordinates[1])
                .attr("r", 5)
                .style("fill", "red");
    });
</script>
```

I have tried following different tutorial and howto's like from [bost.ocks.org](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769909/d3-js-plotting-points-on-zoomable-clickable-map) where it's with a csv file, but no matter what I do it won't draw the circle, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked that the coordinates are within your displayed area? The circle may be drawn where you can't see it.

Comment: [33.46764,112.0785] is in China, [33.46764, -112.0785] is in Arizona

Comment: I think that Lars and Adam are on the right track and if you need another tutorial, [this may be of use](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adam Pearce is correct that the coordinates are [33.46764, -112.0785], however there is another problem: when translating from lat-long to the coords, you need to pass longitude as the first parameter, not latitude!

The tricky thing is that the albers projection, if called with a value not in (lower 48, alaska, hawaii) returns null silently.

Trying to translate [33.46764, -112.0785] in the console:

```
> proj = d3.geo.albersUsa()
function albersUsa(coordinates) {
      var x = coordinates[0], y = coordinates[1];
      point = null;
      (lower48Point(x, y), point) || (alaskaPoint(x, y), point) || hawaiiPoint(x, y);
      return point;
    } d3.v3.js:3257

> proj( [33.46764, -112.0785] )
null

> proj( [-112.0785, 33.46762] )
[241.08874867733104, 327.6295325563234]
```

Bingo. In this case, it was useful to take a look at the actual function we are calling by using the console (in this case, in Chrome).

This was done using d3 version 3.3.8.

Answer (score 4):

Schimmy's answer is correct, however I didn't understand at first. Here's how I added a circle on an Albers map:

```
    //var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();
    var coordinates = projection([-112.0785,33.46764]);
    svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", coordinates[0])
            .attr("cy", coordinates[1])
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use `attr("transform", "translate")` rather than `attr("cx", coor[0].attr("cy", coor[1])`.

If you have a GeoJson fie of the US and you want to plot a circle on each county:

```
  // us = the geoJson file

  svg.append("circle")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "red");
```

You may find this much more efficient than `"cx"` and `"cy"`.

From http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/