# Scaling the Y-axis above X-axis

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, charts

[image]for this example http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/8/. How to increase the Y-axis above X-axis also ?

```
 main.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(yAxis)
```

what change should I make in this line  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)') ?

Comment: What do you mean by "increase the Y-axis above X-axis also"?

Comment: Like the Y-axis in the image(attached to the question) Lars

Comment: So you want two identical plots on top of each other, sharing an x axis?

Comment: Yes Lars, but the plot on the top should have just data points whereas the plot on the bottom remains unchanged as in jsfiddle example.

Comment: You would need to run the same code again (minus the line plotting part) with a translation.

Comment: Thanks Lars, Can you show it on jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to run the code for plotting the chart again (minus the line plotting part) on another `g` element that has been translated. In order to do this, it's easiest to wrap the part that draws the graph in a function and call that twice.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/18/).

Comment: Lars I would like to add this projection http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3734327 to the chart on the top, while the chart at the bottom remains same. Can you guide me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Basically I want to get something like this http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html in place of the chart on the top.

Comment: Just don't call the function I've created twice on the different container elements but add the chart you want to the top.

Comment: I am able to add the chart http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3734327 Lars. But the datapoints must be visible on the chart too. How do I get this ?

Comment: Yes Lars I have seen this tutorial. But in my case I want the background of chart on top http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/18/ to be http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3734327. Or can I use an image in the background using css ?

Comment: You can do both. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987535/plotting-points-on-a-map-with-d3) may help.

Comment: File not found Lars, the bl.ocks.org link not working

Comment: Well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769909/d3-js-plotting-points-on-zoomable-clickable-map) is another question about the same thing. There are lots more you can find on google/SO.